# How can I detect through a web browser if an iPad is running in accessibility mode?

Tags: html, ipad, accessibility

I want to detect using JavaScript/PHP/HTML if the user on iPad is running in accessibility mode. It has to detect this in the browser.

If it is in accessibility mode I want to feed the iPad a different HTML page primed for screenreaders. Is this possible?

Comment: Curious, are there any specific issues you're trying to address here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about HTML5 myself but I have fortunately just scanned through an article in the PragPub online magazine which discussed [HTML5's accessibility features](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2010-10/html-accessibility-for-all). Perhaps there is something there that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: you don't, because it's not possible. There's no [reliable] way to detect whether a user is using a screenreader, either by javascript or via user agent headers. (There's some hacks you can use to guess the presence of a screenreader on a Windows machine, but I don't know of any counterpart for iPad/iOS.)

Longer answer is: you don't, because you can't make any meaningful assumptions about what a user's abilities or disabilities are: instead, try to serve up a page that is already as accessible as possible, and if necessary, and as a last resort, put links to fallback content on the page itself. HTML5's accessibility features make it possible to have a page that is both visually engaging and interactive *and* screenreader-friendly.

As an example of why you can't make assumptions, a user might be using VoiceOver not because they are blind, but because they want to use it to obtain keyboard navigation. Or they might have low vision, so want some assistance from the screenreader, but still want to see the overall layout, graphics, diagrams, and so on.

For what it's worth, it was somewhat common many years back to provide text-only fallback pages for users with disabilities to use. This may have made some sense back when screenreaders could not cope at all with CSS and Javascript, and before the WAI-ARIA properties it was simply not possible to create pages that were both interactive and accessible. This approach is very much out-of-favor at the moment - see [this article at WebAIM - Accessiblity In Mind](http://webaim.org/articles/design/textonly) for some of the issues with this approach. While this article is very much about text-only approaches, much of it likely applies with any form of "accessibility version" of pages.